# How to change label's height by code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

How to change label's height by code? And how to delete the constraint by code?

I've already connected the height constraint of label to the swift file like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var prepareLabelHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

What else should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: `prepareLabelHeigth.constant = yourValue`  this for change the height and to inactive you can  `prepareLabelHeigth.isActive = false`, and please post your code as code, never as image, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
prepareLabelHeight.constant = Intvalue
```